# Determinant of elementary matrix of type 2

Tags: matrices, determinant

I would like to have an induction proof of why the determinant of an elementary matrix with two rows swapped equals -1. I'm brand new to determinants. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the definition [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html). swap two rows only changes "the number of permutation inversions in permutation p". Either from odd to even or from even to odd.

I think the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Levi-Civita_symbol) is a good definition to start with.